# How to write a JavaScript function that works both as a first-class function and higher-order function?

Tags: javascript, function, higher-order-functions, first-class-functions

For example let's take the function add. I want to be able to call:

```
add(1, 2)(3, 4)
```

and

```
add(1, 2)
```

using same implementation.
I have tried writing the add function the following way:

```
var add = (a, b) => {
    return (c, d) => {
         return a + b + c + d;
    }
}
```

This will work fine for add(1, 2)(3, 4) but it will not work for add(1, 2). I am not sure how can I check if a function is passed arguments before returning it.

Comment: If you expect `add(1, 2)` to return a number, then you cannot call that number as if it was a function in `add(1, 2)(3, 4)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there is no way for a function (when called) to know whether its return value will also be called like a function or not, the best you can do is to let the return value be callable *and* have a `valueOf` method, so that it can be used directly as a number in a larger expression that expects a number:

```js
function add(...args) {
    let sum = 0;
    const f = function (...args) {
        for (const val of args) sum += val;
        return f;
    }
    f.valueOf = () => sum;
    return f(...args);
}

console.log(+add(1, 2)(3)(4, 5));
```

The "trick" here is that the `+` operator forces its operand to coerce to a number, and this will implicitly call the `valueOf` method of the function-object that `add` evaluates to. That `+` operator is just one of the many ways to get that `valueOf` method called. A few more examples:

```
console.log("result = " + add(1, 2)(3)(4, 5));
console.log(add(1, 2)(3)(4, 5) - 0);
console.log(add(1, 2)(3)(4, 5) * 1);
console.log(Number(add(1, 2)(3)(4, 5)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send a third parameter to `add` function and return either function or value on the basis of that parameter. something like this -

```
var add = (a, b, returnType) => {
    if (returnType === 'function') {
        return (c, d) => {
            return a + b + c + d;
        }
    } else {
        return a + b;
    }
}
```